# jquery remote validation: pass remote data to function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

my code

```
var validator = $("#form-utente").validate( {
    rules: {
        login: { checkLogin: true }
    }
}
```

my "checkLogin" function ...

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkLogin", function(value, element) {
    return eval($.ajax({
        url: "checkLogin.cfm",
        async: false,
        data: {
            login: function() {
                return $("#login").val();
            },
        }
    }).remoteData);
});
```

checkLogin.cfm (remoteData) returns "false", when I need "true", and viceversa.

how i can evaluate remote data? ...

i need something like:

```
rules: {
    login: { checkLogin: function(remoteData) {
        if(remoteData == true) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }}
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'd use the `remote` rule in jquery.validate for validation that uses a remote service.  Your implementation supposes a synchronous call, which according to the jQuery docs might "temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active".  This might get pretty bad if it's being checked after every change or blur event, like the default validation behavior.

Unfortunately, `remote` doesn't provide a hook for you to change how the data you receive is interpreted:

```
success: function(response) {
    ...
    var valid = response === true;
```

While you can override the implementation of `success` when you setup your rules, this would require you to duplicate the logic used by the rule to manage the validation state of the form ([lines 1035 - 1050](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L1035)).

So... let's say you make a small alteration to the plugin along the lines of:

```
success: function(response) {
    ...
    var valid = ($.isPlainObject(param) && param.isValidResponse) ?
        param.isValidResponse(response) : 
        response === true;
```

And then setup your rule as:

```
login: {
    remote: {
        url: "checkLogin.cfm",
        data: {
            login: function() {
               return $("#login").val();
            },
        },
        isValidResponse: function(response) {
            // do something with response
            // return true or false
        }
    }
}
```

You should then be able to parse the response any way that's needed.  Let me know if this helps.