# How to perform jQuery validation for two connected field ( need to check credentials )?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I need to check if email and password are correct to login user, but when I'm calling remote for one field - I don't have other field value in params.

Here is my action for checking credentials:

```
def checkpass 
 user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
 logger.debug "User: #{params[:user][:email]}"
 logger.debug "Pass: #{params[:user][:password]}"
 logger.debug "Devise pass:#{user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])}"
   respond_to do |format|
    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
     format.json { render :json => user }
    end
  end
end
```

jQuery validation(**EDIT**):

```
         'user[password]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            remote: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkpass",
            type: "get",
            data: {
              email: function() { return $("#user_email").val(); }
            }
        }
```

**LOG**

```
      Processing by EditUserController#checkpass as JSON
      Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "email"=>"user@mail.com", "pa
       ssword"=>"[FILTERED]"}
      ←[1m←[35mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."e
       mail" IS NULL LIMIT 1
        User:
       Pass: 123456
```

How can I get both params[:email] and params[:password] both ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the structure of your form...

**(1)** First field to be completed will be the email one.

**(2)** Second field to be completed will be the password one.

**(3)** For reasons unknown that a user enters information first in the password field, then the remote validation plugin has to detect that the email field is not completed or invalid.

Using this logic, the remote method must be in password field to check the email one and finally knows if all the login data is correct or not.

Something you can do, can be found here:

[jquery remote validation: pass remote data to funcion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337144/jquery-remote-validation-pass-remote-data-to-funcion)

Comment: I used remote function, but when I'm calling remote function in password field it tells me that params[:user][:email] is empty.

Comment: your code is not sending the data or value from your password because you need to use data attribute in the remote.

Comment: oh, you are right. Can I show you my code to check for errors, because mine code isn't working...

Comment: Ok, I looked at it, now do this: email: function() { return $("#user_email").val(); }, password: function() { return $("#user_password").val(); }

Comment: Thanks, but look at mine log again, please.

Comment: Look at my comment, in data, add the password value too